# Having problems installing modules on python (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, module, pip

I'm a bit new to using pip to install modules on Python. I believe I have pip installed, however when I try to use the module I've tried to install using pip it says there is no such module. I'll post terminal response to see what happened. I'd really appreciate if somebody can let me know if I'm making a mistake installing modules, thanks for your time.

```
faizrahman@138-38-186-80 ~ % sudo pip install matplotlib
Password:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/faizrahman/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (1.8.0rc1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports-abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib) (0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
faizrahman@138-38-186-80 ~ %
```

Comment: What versions of python are installed on your machine? What specific python version are you using to load the module? `python --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call pip from python3:
`sudo python3 -m pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked very well for me (using IDLE from python.org). I followed the instructions from this blog entry on the honcho website
https://www.honchosearch.com/blog/seo/install-python-modulespackage-using-idle-mac/

In short:

- start the IDLE shell (or your favourite shell that runs your favourite python flavour)
- enter:
  import sys; sys.executable
- this will return the path to the python that's running in your IDLE shell. Copy the python-path.

To install a modules:

- start a system terminal
- paste the python-path
- behind the python-path enter: -m pip install "package-name"